# Formal treatment of RAII and/or safe deallocations in C++

Tags: memory-management, computer-science, language-design, raii

Are there any research papers on formal treatment of RAII and/or safe deallocations in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at "A Mechanized Semantics for C++ Object Construction and
Destruction, with Applications to Resource Management" ([page](http://gallium.inria.fr/~tramanan/cxx/construction/), [different PDF version](http://gallium.inria.fr/~xleroy/publi/cpp-construction.pdf)), which has apparently been submitted to POPL 2012; but AFAIK has not yet been peer reviewed.

There is a section specifically on RAII, although it may not prove what you want:

> We cannot prove a general result guaranteeing the proper encapsulation
>   of resources in classes: this is a matter of program veriﬁcation. We
>   can, however, prove that in a terminating program every construction
>   of a subobject is correctly matched by a destruction.

Disclaimer: I've only briefly skimmed the paper, and I know almost nothing about formal language semantics.